# python3 error : TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'?

Tags: python-3.x

I have this code

```
config.plugins.Times.Updattime = ConfigIP(default=[0, 0], auto_jump=False)
config.plugins.Times.Updattime.value = self.Verif(config.plugins.Times.Updattime.value)

def Verif(self, Valist):
        if int(Valist[0]) < 10:
            if int(Valist[1]) < 10:
                Valist = ['0' + str(Valist[0]), '0' + str(Valist[1])]
            else:
                Valist = ['0' + str(Valist[0]), Valist[1]]
        elif int(Valist[1]) < 10:
            Valist = [Valist[0], '0' + str(Valist[1])]
        else:
            Valist = [Valist[0], Valist[1]]
        return Valist
```

When I try to typing numbers in that option code I have got this error

```
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

The issue on python3 only on python2 no problem ...

Comment: Please make a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so that we can easily try and reproduce the problem. You can [edit] the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it looks like you want to add leading zeros to both elements in an array.

```
valist = [s.zfill(2) for s in valist]
```